# How to run a backup of projects on TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I am looking a way or strategies of backing up my projects on TFS2017.
I don't there is a tool to do full backup / incremental backup or differential backup.
I would appreciate any resource or help .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to run a backup of projects on TFS 2017

AFAIK, TFS does not support backup a single project or some of projects. There are too many dependencies in the database. It only supports backing up the **entire project collection**.

If you still want to backup some of projects instead of the entire project collection, you could try to back up this project collection first, then delete other projects from this project collection and create a new backup project collection containing only the projects you need.

You could use the Scheduled Backups Wizard to makes it easy to back up your databases, which are part of the Azure DevOps Server data tier and are stored in SQL Server:

[Back up and restore databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/back-up-restore?view=azure-devops)

Besides, if you are working with a large deployment and want to protect against data loss while efficiently using limited storage resources, you can configure differential backups as well as full data backups. If you are using SQL Server AlwaysOn, you can take backups of your secondary database. You can also try using backup compression or splitting backups across multiple files.

[Types of backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/backup-db-architecture?view=azure-devops#types-of-backups)

And we could also [manually back up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/manually-backup-tfs?view=azure-devops) data for Azure DevOps Server by using the tools that SQL Server provides